# min-height: 100% doesn't seem to work, div does not take full height

Tags: html, css

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/yLymbNb) to make things easier.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 1.25em;
  background-color: #292c37;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main-app {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

header {
  background-color: wheat;
}

main {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

header, main, footer {
  padding: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-app">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

I would like `.main-app` to take the full available height but as you can see it doesn't do it for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window

Comment: Set `body {
  height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set parent elements height to `100%` as well. In your case, set `body`'s height to `100%`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 1.25em;
  background-color: #292c37;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-app {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

header {
  background-color: wheat;
}

main {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

footer {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  padding: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-app">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `height: 100vh;` instead of 100%.